# Mysql autocommit's relationship with query cache

Tags: python, mysql, caching, autocommit

When I use python's `mysqldb` query data from db, my query takes around 1-3 seconds. But when I add `conn.autocommit(True)`, the query works very quickly (less than 1 second). Is there any relationship between query cache and autocommit?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. it's mysql's python-connector [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42197).